# Subtitle Workshop/Gnome-Subtitles for Mac OS Snow Leopard?

Tags: mac, sync, subtitles

Is there application like [Subtitle Workshop](http://www.urusoft.net/products.php?cat=sw&lang=1), or [Gnome Subtitles](http://gnome-subtitles.sourceforge.net/), but for Mac OS ?

My requirements:

- See the movie( hear too ;) )
- See the subtitles
- **Able to sync the subtitles by clicking one button( sync point ) and by second button make it synced**

Answer (score 1):

[Bitfield](http://www.bitfield.se) makes two apps that deal with subtitles called [iSubtitles](http://www.bitfield.se/isubtitle/index.html) & [SubMerge](http://www.bitfield.se/submerge/index.html).  From what I've seen, those are the best.  There's also a free app I know about called [Jubler](http://www.jubler.org/) but you get what you pay for.  :)

Comment: Jubler seems promising, thanks. Both iSub and SM does not meet the third requirement. It seems to me that this apps solving the lack of subtitle support in Apple products, but not synchronisation of subtitles and movie